# Scraped content getting 'notice: undefined offset' on first load - fixes after refreshing

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping, loading, simple-html-dom

Novice programmer here just starting to learn php and trying to make my very own web scraper. I've done some extensive searching and I can't seem to find a solution.

I created a form to allow users to submit queries which then scrapes images from pinterest and displays the top hits. However, on the first loading of the page after a query has been submitted I get : "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\domwebcrawler.php on line 27" (28 & 29). AFTER X number of refreshes, the page will eventually load with the pictures.

These lines correspond to my lines of code

HTML/PHP

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="domwebcrawler.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />  

</head>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="get">
<input type="text" name="searchquery"> <input type="submit"> <br>
What do you want to search today?

<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
@$query = $_GET["searchquery"];
if (!empty($query)) {
    $dom->load_file('http://pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=' .    urlencode($query));
    $images= $dom->find('.PinHolder img');
    $descriptions = $dom->find('.description');
    $repins = $dom->find('.RepinsCount');

?>
<div class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{"itemSelector": ".pins",    "columnWidth":10}'>
<?php 
    for ($i=0; $i< 20 ; $i++) {
        echo '<div class="pins">'; 
        if($images[$i])
        echo '<div class="pinimg">' . $images[$i] . '</div>';
        if($descriptions[$i])
        echo '<div class="description">'. $descriptions[$i] . '</div>';
        if($repins[$i])
        echo '<div class="repin_count">' . $repins[$i] . '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    };
};

?>
</div>

</body>
<script src="masonry.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.pins {
padding: 1%;
margin:1%;
border:solid 3px black;
width: 200px;
}

.pinimg img{
width:100%;
}
.description, .repin_count {
text-align: center;
}
```

I think it might have something due to the fact that the page loads before all the scraped content is loaded? But I'm not sure!

All help (& criticism of inefficient code) is welcome!

Warm regards

Comment: `print_r` on `$images` and post the results

Comment: I did it and got a huge vertical list of the images+descriptions, etc. At some point the page turned from pictures into a seemingly endless bunch of code from my file. and then the localhost crashed

Answer (score 0):

Your code is assuming there is always something in the [0] spot of $images, $descriptions, and $repins.

Use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to avoid that message

```
if($images[$i])
echo '<div class="pinimg">' . $images[$i] . '</div>';
if($descriptions[$i])
echo '<div class="description">'. $descriptions[$i] . '</div>';
if($repins[$i])
echo '<div class="repin_count">' . $repins[$i] . '</div>';
```

Comment: I put the code in. Now I am getting just 20 blank boxes without the errors. Does that mean that one of my arrays has nothing in the 0 spot? Would a solution to be run a for loop to check each item in each array, and for those spots that are empty to skip over them?

Comment: Then after refreshing multiple times I would end up having the images loaded again -- just like before, but without the Notice Errors in the background.

Comment: @DionWu: Updated the answer now. Try that.

Comment: Hey Amal, thanks for the sticking with me.

On some refreshes, the .pins divs give the same Notice:Undefined offset error as before, but now the errors are contained inside the boxes themselves. On other refreshes, it works just fine.

Is it a problem with the loading of the scraped content then?

Comment: @DionWu: I can't really tell without seeing the complete code.

Comment: I updated the code. It's basically what I posted. Just have some css. Using jQuery and masonry.js plugin as well

Answer (score 0):

@Amal was right on point. Just make sure to add isset. Each of the objects you retrieve are arrays. You are accessing an index of the array that doesn't exist.

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$query = "html";
function print_type($var){
  echo gettype($var);
  echo "</br>";
  if (is_array($var)){
    echo sizeof($var);
  }
  echo "</br>";
}
if (!empty($query)) {
  $dom->load_file('http://pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=' .    urlencode($query));
  $images= $dom->find('.PinHolder img');
  print_type($images);
  $descriptions = $dom->find('.description');
  print_type($descriptions);
  $repins = $dom->find('.RepinsCount');
  print_type($repins);

?>
<html>
<head>
<!-- put some info here-->
<title>Pinterest parser</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
  for ($i=0; $i< 20 ; $i++) {
?>
  <div class="pins">
<?php
    if(isset($images[$i])){
?>
    <div class="pinimg">
<?php
      echo $images[$i]
?>
    </div> <!-- end pinimg -->
<?php
    }
?>
<?php
    if(isset($descriptions[$i])){
?>
  <div class="description">
<?php
      echo $descriptions[$i]
?>
  </div><!-- end description -->
<?php
    }
?>
<?php
    if(isset($repins[$i])){
?>
    <div class="repin_count">
<?php
      echo $repins[$i]
?>
        </div> <!-- end repin_count -->
<?php
   }
?>
  </div><!-- end pins-->
 <?php
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```